# SFTP Server Container Doesn't Show Files?

Tags: docker, sftp, filezilla

I have an app that generates log files. My idea is to make SFTP docker container, mount my folder where i save logs and access them via FileZilla. I  am able to create container with this compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
sftp-server:
  image: emberstack/sftp
  environment:
    - USERS=demo:demo:1001:1001
  expose:
    - "22"
  volumes:
    - ../wedofinance-backend/logs:/sftp
  ports:
    - "22:22"
networks:
  wedofinance-network:
```

When i access my docker container with:

```
`docker exec -it docker-sftp-server-1 /bin/bash`
```

and then:

```
'ls /sftp'
```

i am able to see all my folders:

[image]

If i go and add some folder/file to my folder that i mounted, in this case folder 'test':

[image]

i am able to see it in my container without having to restart it. Running ls after creating 'test' folder shows that test folder is visible from container:

[image]

The problem is when i try to access my folders and files remotely  via FileZilla or WinSCP i am not able to see those folders/files:

[image]

I tried Server->Force Showing Hidden Files but to no success.

It is worth mentioning that i use SFTP in my FileZilla connection settings.

Any help would be much appreciated as i am new to the dockers and file transfer protocols.

Comment: My first thought about this is a permissions issue on user demo, check permissions and change as needed. Check the group read permissions and make sure user demo is in that group

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some time i noticed that in my container i only had sftp folder because that is where i mounted my logs folder in my docker-compose file and that was the folder where all my files were stored but fileZilla and WinSCP were accessing home/demo/sftp and that folder was empty. After i changed my compose file to:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
#----------------------------------------------------------------
  sftp-server:
      image: emberstack/sftp
      environment:
        - USERS=demo:demo:1001:1001
      expose:
        - "22"
      volumes:
        - ../wedofinance-backend/logs:/home/demo/sftp
      ports:
        - "22:22"
#----------------------------------------------------------------
networks:
  wedofinance-network:
```

i was able to see and download my log files.